# Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following SMTP Error: Data not accepted

Tags: php

The following code gives the message

```
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following SMTP Error: Data not accepted. But when I replace $EmailAdd with a a@yahoo.com. The mail was sent.
```

What's wrong with my code? I'm kind of new in php, especially in dealing with mail functions.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT Email_Address FROM participantable where IDno=$studId";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $EmailADD = $row1["Email_Address"];
}

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

include("class.phpmailer.php");
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = $mail->getFile('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "jsbadiola@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "********";            // GMAIL password
$mail->AddReplyTo("jsbadiola@gmail.com","Lord Skyhawk");
$mail->From       = "jsbadiola@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Update";
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via gmail";
$mail->Body       = "Hi,<br>This is the HTML BODY<br>";                      //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->WordWrap   = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($EmailADD, "Agta ka");
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");             // attachment
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $status = "Successfully Save!";
    header("location: User_retsched.php?IDno=$studId&status=$status&Lname=$Lname&Fname=$Fname&Course=$Course&Year=$Year");
}
```

Comment: You should go change your gmail password....

Comment: but when i change $EmailAdd to a real email address like sunshine@yahoo.com then it sends the mail.

Comment: i tried his gmail password - didn't work

Comment: i did not put the real password for the security of the account but it does really work, the problem was i cannot get the value of the email address from the the database. maybe that was the problem, but i dont know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 7):

Most times I've seen this message the email gets successfully sent anyway, but not always.  To debug, set:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
```

You can either echo the debug messages or log them using [`error_log()`](http://php.net/error_log):

```
// 'echo' or 'error_log'
$mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
```

A likely candidate especially on a heavily loaded server are the SMTP timeouts:

```
// default is 10
$mail->Timeout = 60;
```

`class.smtp.php` also has a `Timelimit` property used for reads from the server.

Comment: I was attaching a file that was too big for sending and the debugging tips helped me to determine that. Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU ANIMISM!!!!! For all those people having RANDOM "Data Not Accepted" errors on code you 'KNOW' works elsewhere (and your 'new server' acts up), try setting your $mail->Timeout to something greater than 10 (60 works perfectly..). I have been trying to find out what is causing this for weeks now, and with no luck until I found this post. Some servers apparently just cant handle the 10 second default, and need a little extra umph in this area. Don't believe? Try setting this to something even smaller than 10, like 5 or 2. Than try to set it to 60, note that this IS consistent!

Answer (score 4):

It also helps if you have not exceeded your daily sending limit of Googles Spam inforcement.

Comment: A source link or the actual limit might be helpful.

Comment: This is the answer.. I think they limit you to 1000 or less emails a day (outgoing via SMTP)

Answer (score 3):

check you query to the db output & variable value at that point in the script. make sure it's returning the desired value for $EmailADD .

do a var_dump($EmailADD, true);

or try to echo somewhere the output of that query. If your actually receiving an email value from that query, I don't see why it shouldn't work, specially when you mention that assigning a value directly works; without sql query.

Comment: +1: I had the same error msg and invalid email in the AddAddress method was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different SMTP server? See if that works?

Or just don't use an smtp server, most servers with PHP on also have sendmail/postfix, so can relay email themselves.

remove this bit ...

```
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier

$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server

$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->Username   = "jsbadiola@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username

$mail->Password   = "alucar";            // GMAIL password
```

Comment: the SMTP work sir, but i think that the problem is on getting the email address fromt he database.